# In typescript, how to define type of async function

Tags: typescript

I tried to define a type of async function, but failed in compilation, see below:

```
interface SearchFn {
    async (subString: string): string;
}

class A {
    private Fn: SearchFn
    public async do():Promise<string> {
        await this.Fn("fds") // complain here: cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
        return ''
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me work this out?

Comment: Promise<boolean> doesn't work?

Comment: Please show how/where you are defining `Fn`.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

It works if you just declare the return type of the function to be a Promise:

```
interface SearchFn {
    (subString: string): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

or as a type declaration:

```
type SearchFn = (subString: string) => Promise<boolean>;
```

Microsoft's TS Linter will recommend this second syntax.

Comment: Smart, thank you, async func actually is a Promise returned function.

Comment: @Ron worth mentioning thats not correct, async function simply uses await. See Motti's answer

Comment: People should note that a function that returns a promise is not necessarily an async function.

Comment: what if there's no returned value? `): Promise<undefined>` is failing for me. I just need an async function so I can use `await` inside it...

Comment: @dcsan Promise<void>

Answer (score 111):

The `async` keyword is used to indicate to the compiler/runtime that the function in question will use `await` internally (so it can put in the required [scaffolding to enable it](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/modern-javascript-and-asynchronous-programming-generators-yield-vs-async-await-550275cbe433)).

This means that `async` only has meaning for the **implementation** of the function, not it's **interface**. Therefore having `async` on an interface's method isn't useful, you want to say that the function returns a certain `Promise` (in your case `Promise<string>`) but you don't want to enforce that the interface's implementer implements this in a certain way (using `await`).

So as other said before me:

```
interface SearchFn {
    (subString: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

Then, whoever chooses to implement this function can choose to use `async`, plain old `Promise.then` or perhaps even some new methodology that will come up in the future.

Comment: Not quite. Functions marked `async` also return promises. So `async function x() { return true; }` returns a type of `Promise<boolean>`. So personally, I think the Typescript team messed up here and should have allowed using async in templates to indicate that methods return promises. But nobody asked me. ;)

Answer (score 17):

Pass the type of the returned object to the Promise generic.

```
type SearchFn = (subString: string): Promise<string>;
```

Alternatively you can declare an `AsyncFunction` generic type.

```
type AsyncFunction <A,O> = (...args:A) => Promise<O> 
type SearchFn = AsyncFunction<[string], string>
```

AsyncFunction is a type generic that receives two type variables - the type of the input(A), and the type of the output.

Answer (score 3):

That's a tricky topic. A function marked with `async` will return a `Promise`. But returning a `Promise` and using `async` are not equivalent. I will explain why.

For example, in your case you can define your interface like this:

```js
interface Foo {
    (source: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

Then you have different options to write a function that complies with the interface:

```js
// complies
const foo1: Foo = (input: string) => {
  return Promise.resolve(input);
};

// complies
const foo2: Foo = async (input: string) => {
  return Promise.resolve(input);
};

// complies: the return value gets wrapped in a Promise
const foo3: Foo = async (input: string) => {
  return input;
};
```

Now, one of the magical behaviors of the `async` keyword, is that the returned value will get wrapped in a `Promise`. For example:

```js
// valid
async function bar1(): Promise<number> {
  return 5;
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that promises get automatically flattened (but I don't know how that works internally), so the following code is valid:

```
// valid
async function bar2(): Promise<Promise<number>> {
  return Promise.resolve(5);
}

// also valid... weird
async function bar3(): Promise<Promise<number>> {
  return 5;
}
```

So far, there is no meaningful difference between using `async` and `Promise`, so one could argue that `async` is not a keyword that belongs in interfaces, because you can express the contract in terms of promises. It's just a syntax sugar so we can use the `await` keyword. An implementation detail, right?

Sadly. Is is not. There is one additional effect of the `async` keyword that does affect the contract and has to do with the nature of promises.

Look at the following function:

```js
// supposedly compliant
function nonAsyncFunction(input: number): Promise<void> {
  if (input < 0) {
    throw new TypeError('"input" should be positive');
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Harmless, right? If you handle the error using `try/catch` (using `await` in the function call), there is no problem. But if you were to do handle the error using `Promise.prototype.catch`:

```js
// The function throws before returning a promise, so it's not part of the promise chain
nonAsyncFunction(-1)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('caught!');
  });
```

The error will not be caught, because when the function throws and an exception is raised, instead of returning a `Promise`.

On the other hand, a function like the following will return a rejected promise and you can catch it either with `try/catch` or `Promise.prototype.catch`:

```js
async function asyncFunction(input: number): Promise<void> {
  if (input < 0) {
    throw new TypeError('"input" should be positive');
  }

  return;
}
```

The root of the problem is that we have two ways of reporting errors, one by "rejecting" promises and other by raising errors. We have no way of enforcing a function that returns a `Promise` that it reports errors using only promises as well.

In conclusion, `async` is not equivalent to defining the return type as `Promise`. In practice, using `async` ensures any error raised will be returned as a rejected promise, which is a valuable thing to enforce. Sadly, it is not possible to define an `async` function in an interface.

The correct answer to your question would be that **it can't be done**, strictly speaking.