# Typescript - facing issue Property is not assignable to the same property in base type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm having an issue in Typescript. I've created two interfaces one for class and other for function which is defined inside the class.
This is the interface of my Schedule class

```
interface scheduleClass { 
getScheduleLists(): showListsInterface
}
```

This is the interface of my show lists function.

```
interface showListsInterface {
  status: string;
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  data: Promise<Schedule[]>
}
```

This is the schedule class

```
export class scheduleServices implements scheduleClass{
async getScheduleLists(){
    try {
        const schedules = await Schedule.findAll();
        return {
            status:"success",
            statusCode:200,
            message:"",
            data:schedules
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            status:"error",
            statusCode:500,
            message:error.message,
            data:[]

        }
    }

}
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Very similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744159/in-typescript-how-to-define-type-of-async-function

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is incorrect. `async` functions always return a `Promise`, but your type is an object that has a promise as part of it. It needs to be a promise of the entire thing.

I'd make the type without the promise:

```typescript
interface showListsInterface {
  status: string;
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  data: Schedule[];
}
```

then the function's return type is `Promise<showListsInterface>`.

I was going to say "or change the function to return an object with a promise in it" but I see the other parts of the object rely on knowing whether the asynchronous part worked, so that's not an option in this specific case.