# TS2322: Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

In my react app, I m trying to import the img source, but getting any error as

`TS2322: Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.`  how to fix it or what is the correct way to import an element in variable?

here is my code:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import "./barkingRoad.scss";



const BarkingRoad: FC = () => {

const slidex = import("./../../../../assets/images/small/boomerang-site1.jpg");

return (
    <div className="boomerang-slider-barkingRoad">
    
        <div className="project-data">
            <div className="boomerang-site-slide">
                <div className="prev"><a href="#">Previus</a> </div>
                <div>
                    <img src={slidex} /> //getting error
                </div>
                <div className="next"><a href="#">Next</a> </div>
                {/* srcSet={`${slide} 360w, ${slide} 768w, ${slide} 1366w  `} */}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
)
```

}

```
export default BarkingRoad;
```

**This is works:**

```
const slidex = require("./../../../../assets/images/small/boomerang-site1.jpg");
```

but getting an error as ;

```
 8:20  error  Require statement not part of import statement
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two options.

1. Import outside the component like this.

`const slidex = require("...");`

```
const BarkingRoad: FC = () => {
...
}
```

2. Use `await` keyword.

   ```
    const BarkingRoad: FC = async () => {
    ...
    const slidex = await require...
    }
   ```

If you defined the image in the public directory, you can use the url, instead of importing in the code.

Comment: Cannot find name 'async'. - error raising

Comment: `Type '() => Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Promise<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)
const BarkingRoad: React.FC<{}>`

Comment: Seems like you are using `typescript`. Take a look at this one to get to know how to define `async` function in typescript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744159/in-typescript-how-to-define-type-of-async-function

Comment: Yes, I agree. But my case i am not able to get the correct way of declaration, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

**`const slidex = import` is dynamic import so retuning a `promise<any>` and `src` recieves a direct url string**

Try to set it directly:

```
<img src="./../../../../assets/images/small/boomerang-site1.jpg" />
```

Comment: I am trying to load in ts file instead of image, require for dynamic process

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this:

```
import slidex from "./../../../../assets/images/small/boomerang-site1.jpg";
```

Comment: I am getting error as `An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.`

Comment: put this import statement above `const BarkingRoad: FC = () => {`

Answer (score 0):

The import function returns a Promise which is not a string.

Your could use the following solutions:

- [Use path in src-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66355497/9415076)
- [Use a regular import](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)
- Or await the import like

```
 const BarkingRoad: FC = async () => {   
 ...
 const slidex = await import('...');
 ...
```

Comment: `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.` when i use `const slidex = await import('...');`

Comment: As siruis suggested you also have to add the async keyword. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69115984/9415076)